# Trouble returning an object from a class I created

Tags: c++, class, object, return-type

I have this class (hashMap.h):

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include "functions.h"
using std::cout;
using std::vector;
using std::endl;
using std::string;

class hashMap
{
public:
    explicit hashMap(int hashEntrySize = 101) : hashVector(nextPrime(2 * hashEntrySize)), currentSize{ 0 }
    {}

    bool containsKey(const string & searchKey);
    bool containsVector(const vector<string> searchVector);
    void insert(const string & keyTarget, const vector<string> & insertVector);
    void insertAfterReHash(const string & keyTarget, const vector<string> & insertVector);

    int getCurrentSize() const;
    void assignKey(string & newKey);

private:
    enum EntryType { ACTIVE, EMPTY, DELETED };
    struct hashEntry
    {
        vector<string> vectorValue;
        EntryType status;
        int keyID;
        string key;

        hashEntry(EntryType s = EMPTY)
            :status(s), keyID{ -1 } {}
    };

    size_t hashFunction(const string & key);
    bool isActive(int currentPos) const;
    int findPos(const string & keyTarget);
    void reHash();

    vector<hashEntry> hashVector;
    int currentSize;
};
```

And a function header file (functions.h):

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using std::string;
using std::cout;
using std::vector;
using std::endl;
using std::cin;
using std::ifstream;
using std::getline;


hashMap computeAdjacentWords(const vector<string> & words) //error at this line
{
    hashMap hm(500);

    //do stuff with object

    return hm;
}
```

And the main file:

```
#include <iostream>>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include "hashMap.h"

using std::string;
using std::cout;
using std::vector;
using std::endl;
using std::cin;
using std::ifstream;
using std::getline;

int main()
{
    vector<string> words;
    string line;
    ifstream dictionaryFile;

    dictionaryFile.open("largedictionary.txt");
    words = readinWords(dictionaryFile);
    dictionaryFile.close();

    hashMap hm = computeAdjacentWords(words);

    return 0;
}
```

I created the hashMap class and I want to be able to return a hashMap object, but this is giving me an error of "Error C4430 missing type specifier - int assumed." What am I doing wrong?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, paying attention to the "complete" part.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I read it. I specified where the error occurs. I posted exactly what was wrong and I would have no idea about what context I'm missing since I've never received this error before. I know it's this function causing problems because it compiles fine until I add this function.

Comment: The compiler doesn't understand one of your types, either `hashMap`, `vector` or `string`. For the `vector` and `string` you may (and **should** always) specify `std::` beforehand. Ensure your compiler knows what these objects are

Comment: FYI @Ghost_Stark, a complete example would probably include the declaration of `hashMap` and a `main()` function calling `computeAdjacentWords`. That would be a complete example that would produce the error.

Comment: Again, you do not appear to understand what "complete" means, on the help page. You didn't even explain which specific line is referenced in the compiler diagnostic, the function declaration, the variable declaration, or the return statement.

Comment: @Tas Yeah i'm using std::vector and std::string at the top of the file. I even included the hashMap class, and I'm getting the same error. And thanks for the answer. I'm still trying to figure it out.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I honestly thought this would end up being some easy fix I was overlooking and didn't see the need to post everything. I'm editing the question with more of the code.

Comment: The compiler doesn't know what `hashMap` is. When it reaches the line with the error, the `hashMap` symbol was not yet declared or defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put the code in files and nicely asked the compiler to do its job. This is the first warning from the list:

```
$ cc main.cpp -c
In file included from main.cpp:5:
In file included from ./hashMap.h:6:
./functions.h:16:1: error: unknown type name 'hashMap'
hashMap computeAdjacentWords(const vector<string> & words) //error at this line
^
```

The compiler doesn't know what `hashMap` is. When it reaches the line with the error, the `hashMap` symbol was not yet declared or defined.

You shouldn't define functions in header files.

Rename `functions.h` to `functions.cpp`, add `#include "functions.h"` at the end of the list of includes.

Create a new file `functions.h` that contains only the declarations of the functions (the function header) and the types they use:

```
#ifndef __FUNCTIONS_H__
#define __FUNCTIONS_H__

#pragma once
//#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
//#include <fstream>
#include "hashMap.h"

using std::string;
using std::vector;
// Do you really need all these types here?
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::cin;
using std::ifstream;
using std::getline;


hashMap computeAdjacentWords(const vector<string> & words);

#endif // __FUNCTIONS_H__
```

Comment: Thanks this was the problem! I was including all those types because I was originally defining the functions in the header and they were going to be using those types. Also, can't I avoid using the `#ifndef` and `#define` directives by using `#pragma once`?

Comment: Errr... I don't know about `#pragma once`. Once upon a time when I was coding in `C++` the `#ifndef/#define/#endif` set was the standard way to guard a header file against multiple inclusion. Afaik, `#pragma` is an extension point for compile writers. If it works with `#pragma once` with your compiler then go for it. But be aware that it can have a different effect (most probably be ignored) if you use another compiler that doesn't understand it.

Comment: Strongly recommend not `using` things in header file  ; instead spell out the prefixes in the function declarations. This is because code which includes this header cannot put the cat back in the bag

Answer (score 0):

You are including functions.h from hashmap.h *BEFORE* the hashMap class is defined. As such, when the compiler reads functions.h, the hashMap class is not defined.